# Cannot extract text from a column in layout dxl if the column is itself layout dxl

Tags: ibm-doors

I have a bunch of columns in a view. Some of the columns are layout dxl.

When I use this code in immediate mode, it will print the text of the column. Assume that column 7 is layout dxl rather than an attribute.

```
Object o = current
Column c = column(7)
string s = text(c, o)
print s
```

However, when I try to put the equivalent into layout dxl for column 18, not only does nothing show up in column 18, but no display statements after the code snippet will show up, either.

```
Column c = column(7)
string s = text(c, obj)
display s
display "all done"
```

I.e., in the above code, column 18 is empty. Not even "all done" is displayed in the column.

(I am trying to do some processing based on the contents of text, but I'm skipping all that in this question because this is the crux of what isn't working.)

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. There is no guarantee that by the time the value of column 18 is being computed the value of column 7 has already been computed. In fact, as far as I know, getting the value of a column in another column should not even work when you have fixed values like Absolute Number. But when you actually try to display a DXL column in another colum (which calls another calculation), I am quite sure that you create an endless loop of calculations or at least a mutual lock.

In immediate Mode, every column has already been computed and displayed, so retrieving the text of a column works without problems.

Use attribute DXL for column 7 and in column 18 display the value of that attribute to achieve your goal. DOORS makes sure that all attribute DXL has already been calculated by the time the columns of views are calculated